# Show that if we had a complete metric space $X$ with no isolated points, then every singleton $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

My attempt:

The closure of the singleton is again the singleton itself
Since there are no isolated points, then clearly $\{ x \}$ does not contain any non-empty open set hence the interior of the singleton is empty. Hence $\{x \}$ is no where dense.

I feel as though I am missing something - why is the need of completeness required

edit: I am trying to apply the Baire Category Theorem to this, i.e. I know that since $X$ is complete with no isolated points then it is not countable.

Answer (score 0):

Your argumentation is correct and completeness is not necessary.

In a $T_1$ space every singleton set is closed: For any points $p, x$ let $U_p(x)$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ not containing $p$, then $\bigcup_{x \in X} U_p(x) = X-\{p\}$ is open. Metric spaces are $T_1$, eg $B_{d(x,p)}(x)$ and $B_{d(x,p)}(p)$ satisfy the $T_1$ condition for $x,p$.

A point is called not isolated if every open neighbourhood of it contains other points. This means that if $p$ is not isolated then $\{p\}$ cannot contain any open subsets other than $\emptyset$.

So for every point that is not isolated $int(cl(\{p\}))=int(\{p\})=\emptyset$